# SQL join eliminating repeated columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

So I dispose of a few tables which were all generated out of a single, common one.

Their schemas are as

`T1: A, B, C, M, N
 T2: A, B, J, M
 T3: A, C, M, P`

and the expected result is a joined version of all tables discarding the repeated values.

`R: T1.A, T1.B, T1.C, T2.J, T1.M, T1.N, T3.P`

Fortunately, rows' attributes coincide on homonymous columns, ie.

`T1.A == T2.A == T3.A` across all rows

`T1.B = T2.B` across all rows

etc.

What would be a query to join those tables into a single `R` table keeping only uniquely-named columns as above?

Comment: select only the columns you need when you join the tables, like Select t1.A,t2.j....... (join tables).

Comment: Simply name the columns you need in your select statement: `t1.A, t1.B, t1.c`, etc

Comment: Just for fun, check out NATURAL JOINs.

Comment: @jarlh Exactly what I was looking for, ```SELECT * FROM T1 NATURAL JOIN T2 NATURAL JOIN T3;```

Answer (score 1):

```
select T1.A, T1.B, T1.C, T2.J, T1.M, T1.N, T3.P
from t1 join t2 
on t1.A = t2.A and t1.B = t2.B and t1.M = t2.M
join t3 on
t1.A = t3.A and t1.C = t3.C and t1.M = t3.M
```

You have to `join` the tables.

Answer (score 1):

The basic query would be:

```
 SELECT T1.A, T1.B, T1.C, T2.J, T1.M, T1.N, T3.P
 FROM T1
 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.A=T2.A and T1.B=T2.B and T1.M=T2.M
 INNER JOIN T3 ON T1.A=T3.A and T1.C=T3.C and T1.M=T3.M
```

The number of conditions you put on each inner join should equal all the columns that make it a unique row for that table. For example, if A,B,and M is sufficient to make it unique then you must use those. Indexing coverage (as separate or thorough clustered) should encompass these fields that make them unique together.

Answer (score 0):

Although other solutions are correct, a more elegant version would be

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
NATURAL JOIN T2
NATURAL JOIN T3
```